# Why use Dictionary over a list of objects with two named properties?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a conceptual reason why a dictionary is preferred over a 2-entry tuple or an object with two properties?

```
Dictionary<int, string> userIdAndNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

vs

```
List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
```

Where Users is defined as:

```
public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ease of use. It avoids the need to define a new type for every simple key:value relation that doesn't require additional logic built in.

Comment: Because the the dictionary key is placed in hash buckets for fast retrieval.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "conceptual"?  Since you don't seem concerned with the implementation details and performance, what are you concerned with?  The conceptual difference is that one is looked up by ordinal index, the other is looked up by key (could be a number, could be a string, could be a blob of data)

Answer (score 6):

To do look ups using a `UserId` with the `List<User>`, you have to iterate over half the list on average to find the matching user. The number of operations is proportional to the size of the `List`.

When using the `Dictionary` on average, you only have to do a constant number of operations with respect to the number of entries in the `Dictionary`. Read more about the algorithm that powers a dictionary on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assumed that there was a performance penalty for using lists of objects, but is there any conceptual difference between the two?

Comment: My apologies! Performance is the first thing that comes to my mind when I see a Dictionary. The article that the community provided is way more comprehensive than my response. It goes well beyond performance.